# How to remove string from an array that are less than a certain length?

Tags: python, arrays, string

So, I'm scraping the text off or a website and now I am looking to weed out the useless content and keep the meat of the article.

Here is a piece of what my array looks like:

```
[u'ADVERTISEMENT', u'\n            \n                By\n                \n\n\n                            \n                             Matthew Rocco\n                            \n                           \t\t\n\n\nPublished\n                January 18, 2017\n\nOil\n\n\n\n                            FOXBusiness\n\n', u'\n                    \n                    \n                    \n                        (Reuters)\n                    \n                ', u'Exxon Mobil (XOM) has joined a growing list of oil producers who are expanding in the Permian Basin of Texas, betting that America\u2019s shale boom is far from over.', u'Continue Reading Below', u'The world\u2019s largest publicly traded oil company inked a deal with the Bass family of Fort Worth, Texas, to double its footprint in the Permian. Exxon will pay up to $6.6 billion, mostly in stock, for approximately 275,000 acres of land. Exxon said 250,000 of those acres are located in the Permian, the largest oil field in America.', u'The acquisition is Exxon\u2019s most expensive move since its 2010 buyout of XTO Energy, which made Exxon the nation\u2019s top natural-gas producer. The deal is also Exxon\u2019s first under new CEO Darren Woods, who replaced Rex Tillerson after he was tapped as President-elect Donald Trump\u2019s nominee for Secretary of State.', u'\u201cThe deal doubles [Exxon\u2019s] estimated resources in place in the Permian, and sets the stage, in our view, for years of drillable inventory,\u201d CFRA Research analyst Stewart Glickman wrote in a note to clients.',...]
```

I want to remove any item that is less than a particular length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a condition:

```
old_list =   ## your example
limit =      ## minimum length
new_list = [str for str in old_list if len(str) >= limit]
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise response. This is perfect.